# Power BI Column Chart of Project Count Per Priority

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, sharepoint-online, powerbi-desktop

I need to create a report under Power BI.

I have used a SharePoint list as a backend. I have created a list that contains two fields.

- Title - Single line of text
- Priority - Choice

I need to create a chart under PowerBi that displays a count of projects based on Priority.

For example,

Project 1 - High

Project 2 - Medium

Project 3 - Low

Project 4 - High

Project 5 - Low

I need Counts as mentioned below,

High - 2

Medium - 1

Low - 2

Please refer to the below screenshot to check the SharePoint list data.

SharePoint List Screenshot

[image: SharePoint List Screenshot]

Can anyone help me with the same?

Comment: Can anyone share their own thoughts on the below link?

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-remove-Tile-Header-from-PowerBI-report-while-adding-in/m-p/1673866#M426043

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we get the values from your screenshot:

| Title | Priority |
| --- | --- |
| Project 1 | Medium |
| Project 2 | Low |
| Project 3 | High |
| Project 4 | Medium |
| Project 5 | High |
| Project 6 | Low |
| Project 7 | Medium |
| Project 8 | High |
| Project 9 | Medium |
| Project 10 | Low |

There are 3 projects with High priority, 4 with Medium, and 3 with Low. Put a stacked bar chart visual in your report, add `Priority` field to `Axis` property, and add `Title` field to `Values` (because it is text, it will be summarized as `Count of`, but if necessary, right click it and adjust the summarization). This is the result you will get:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have created a report with the SharePoint Online list. But the report is not refreshing while new data updating in the SharePoint list. Is there any workaround for the same?

Comment: You can read about the data refresh in Power BI [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/refresh-data).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have created PowerAutomate and resolved that refresh issue.

Comment: Can you please share your thoughts on the below link?

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-remove-Tile-Header-from-PowerBI-report-while-adding-in/m-p/1673866#M426043

Answer (score 0):

You can easily load a Sharepoint List in Power BI.

In the ribbon, "Get data", "More", keyword "Sharepoint".
Once you've successfully loaded the list, it is basically a Table.

Then, to create a pie chart of count of project per priority:

1. Choose the pie-chart visualisation
2. Drag `Priority` in the "Details" field.
3. Drag  `Title` in Values. If not already selected, choose "Count" as aggregation function.

Comment: Can you please share your thoughts on the below link?

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Power-Apps/How-to-remove-Tile-Header-from-PowerBI-report-while-adding-in/m-p/1673866#M426043